# The end of a parasha as a message for the new parasha

Tags: sources-mekorot, parsha-torah-portion

The Shaloh [(Introduction to Torah Shebikthav, Vayeishev, Mikeitz, Vayigash)](https://www.sefaria.org/Shenei_Luchot_HaBerit%2C_Torah_Shebikhtav%2C_Vayeshev%2C_Miketz%2C_Vayigash%2C_Introduction.2?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) explains for example that there is:

> a time and place for everything

Similary, the Shaloh writes [(Shenei Luchot HaBerit, Torah Shebikhtav, Matot, Masei, Devarim, Torah Ohr)](https://www.sefaria.org/Shenei_Luchot_HaBerit%2C_Torah_Shebikhtav%2C_Matot%2C_Masei%2C_Devarim%2C_Torah_Ohr.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> כי הוא דבר בעתו their content is most appropriate at that time.

Refer also the the [sefer Emunas Iteicha by Rabbi Wolffsonn (Parshas Balak, p. 169)](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51136&st=&pgnum=169&hilite=).

This got me thinking. Since there is a time and place for everything, is there an idea that that say **that preceding and following parshios are connected by theme/subject/lessons that we are meant to take from it etc..?**

Comment: Every verse is connected to the verses adjacent to it. Why do you need a special source for this case?

Comment: the ending of a parasha is not always connected by theme to the next one....

Comment: On the contrary, you just haven't asked about each yet. Same with every other two adjacent topics (eg. Nazir and Sotah)

Comment: What if someone breaks up the parshah differently?

Comment: Is this question so difficult? I am asking for sources that discuss this. The Shaloh for example saw it fitting to discuss the themes of for e.g. the three weeks and connect them to parashios. So my question is whether there are sources that say the themes of ending verses in a parsha are connected to the beginning of the next parsha.

Comment: I don't understand what the Shaloh's statements have to do with the question: He is talking about connecting Parashot [ha-Shavu'a] with the _time of year_ in which they are read. The question seems to be asking about connections between the end of each Parasha and the beginning of the next. Could you clarify that? (Also, the only snippet from the first source that is quoted, is actually from [Kohelet 3:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ecclesiastes.3.1?lang=bi&lang2=en).)

Comment: @TamirEvan he does talk about that yes. But, since there is a time for everything, I was wondering what I asked in my question.

Comment: On the subject of connecting Parashot (though, not necessarily in the sense of the annual Torah reading portions), Hebrew Wikipedia's "[סמיכות פרשיות](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA)" may be worth a read.

Comment: @TamirEvan TY! I might have caused some confusion with the way I formulated the question. I got the idea that there must have been sources that explain that the theme/essence of parasha a, goes on to parasha b. So the theme from parshas Noach, is continued in parshas Lech Lecha etc..

Answer (score 1):

There is a connection that is similar to what you described made by [The Targum Simcha](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=66549&st=&pgnum=23&hilite=) at the end of parshas Vayechi.

He connects the end of Sefer Bereishis, concluding on a somber note with the death of Yaakov, with the beginning of the next sefer which begins with the story of the jewish enslavement.

He ties it in with Purim to give a high spirited message to the reader when beginning the story of Shemos.

Comment: Interesting, that gives us two sources :) I was still hoping that there are (authorative) sources that discuss this idea :)

Answer (score 1):

Unsure if your question is asking for discussions about the weekly parsha being connected to current events or specifically the weekly parsha being connected to the following and previous parsha.

There is a [Famous HaYom Yom](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43302&st=&pgnum=113&hilite=) from Beis Cheshvan which says that "living with the times means living with the weekly parsha"

Comment: Interesting, I forgot about that Hayom Yom. Wonderful one. I updated my question (bald-part). Does this Hayom Yom mean that the lessons we take from the previous parasha, is somehow connected by theme/spiritual lessons we take from the current parasha?