# Parshas Achrei and Pesach

Tags: sources-mekorot, passover, commentaries, torah-reading, parshat-acharei-mot

This year, on Erev Pesach (Monday, April 22, 2024) the Torah reading is parshas Achrei Mot. The [Chabad-website](https://www.chabad.org/calendar/view/day.asp?tdate=04%2F22%2F2024) notifies that the daily reading of Erev Pesach is the 2nd Portion (Vayikra (Leviticus) 16:18-16:24).

I have trouble finding a connection between Pesach, and what the parsha tells us here. Does anyone know if there are connections between this parsha, and Pesach? Vayikra 16:18 is about Yom Kippur.

What I mean is as follows: the Shelah teaches us that each parasha is read in it's appropriate time, davar yafeh beito. So, there must be a deeper reason why Achrei Mos is being read before Pesach. If we read the parasha, what of that parasha is connected with Pesach?

Comment: Parts of acharei mot are read just before pesach in every leap year https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/112106/759

Comment: @DoubleAA I know, and that is why I asked this question. What connection is there?

Comment: The sons of aharon seemingly died in Nissan, so the parsha that is the aftermath likely occurred then as well.

Comment: We do it before the chag because of the principle of אין מפטירין אחר הפסח. (Belated PTIJ?)

Comment: For those that wear a Kitel at the Seder and wear a Kitel on Yom Kipur maybe that can be a connection.

Comment: @GershonGold thanks but I think I wasn't that clear in my question. My apologise. What I meant is as follows: the Shelah teaches us that each parasha is read in it's appropriate time, davar yafeh beito. So, there must be a deeper reason why Achrei Mos is being read before Pesach. If we read the parasha, what of that parasha is connected with Pesach?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.18.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: In one of the volumes of _Sichot Moharash_, I remember reading a story about one of the Chasidic greats (I want to say Levi Yitzchok of Berditchev), who would have Shulchan Aruch open on _Erev Yom Kippur_, and would "steal" learning a few _se'ifim_, in between preparations for the day of awe. One year it was open on _Hilchot Bedikat/Biur Chametz_, and when asks, he said it was relevant, because on _Aseret Yemei Teshuvah_ we strive to remove the _Chametz_ from our hearts.

Comment: Somewhat related: "[The end of a parasha as a message for the new parasha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/138045/1368)" (By the same author, and makes reference to the Shelah connecting certain Parashot ha-Shavua to the time of year they are read.)

Comment: @Dov Thx, but I don't see the connection?!

Comment: "You shall not copy the practices of the land of Egypt where you dwelt" - a reference to the slavery in Egypt / the Pesach story...

Comment: @Dov interesting, also what the Sfas Emes there writes. This year, it falls on Erev Pesach. Pesach is about leaving our limitations, that limit us in avodas Hashem, but Yetzias Mitzrayim also made us Childeren of Hashem, so is that maybe why this parasha is read on Erev Pesach? To remind us to cleave to Hashem and walk in His ways, as per the [Sfas Emes](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefat_Emet%2C_Leviticus%2C_Achrei_Mot.5.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes?